# Check whether the jcheckbox is selected in a table cells in Java SE

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I want to the check the selected check boxes in a table cell after pressing a button and the that selected rows. (The table date will be filled by a DB - Mysql)
Please explain me how to do that with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table's `TableModel` should have a column keeping booleans. `getColumnClass()` for the column should return Boolean.class. Then checkbox will be shown by `DefaultTableCellRenderer`. To get value just use `table.getModel().getValueAt(...)`

Comment: Thanks buddy. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes should have an `ItemListener`.

In the `itemStateChanged()` method, you invoke the `isChecked()` method on the checkbox object and it will return a `BOOL` value on its `check` state.